# WPF: ScrollViewer total content height

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, scrollviewer

I am working on a WPF app. Here is my interface:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollView" CanContentScroll="True">
      <RichTextBox Padding="10" x:Name="TextArea" Background="Transparent" Opacity="0.95" />    
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want to load a text file in to the RichTextBox, which is bigger then the size of the screen and then find out the total size of the contents of scroll viewer(i.e. how far can I actually scroll). In the documentation it says:

> ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight Property
>
> A Double that represents the vertical size of the extent. The default
>   is 0.0.
>
> If CanContentScroll is true, the values of the ExtentHeight,
>   ScrollableHeight, ViewportHeight, and VerticalOffset properties are
>   number of items. If CanContentScroll is false, the values of these
>   properties are Device Independent Pixels.

If understand correctly, the documentation is saying that the `ExtentHeight` should give me the height of my content in units of contents sizes, if `CanContentScroll` is `true`. My RichTextBox is the content of scroll view. So if my RichTextBox is 1000 pixels long, for example, and 500 pixels are visible on screen, then `ExtentHeight` should be 2. However, when I load up an empty `RichEditBox` which completely fits inside `ScrollViewer` without scrolling, and has `ActualHeight` equal to 567, `ExtentHeight` is equal to 37.96, which makes no sense to me. I expect if to be equal to 1 or less then 1. So how do I find the total content size of the TextBox inside ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cause of my issue was that I had my RichTextBox in ScrollViewer. RichTextBox has it own scrolling capabilities, and by sticking it in ScrollViwer it got all mixed up. So I got rid of ScrollViewver and used RichTextBox only with its HeightExtent property.